# Wierd log message when saving a textfile

Tags: objective-c, nssavepanel

I get a message I don´t understan in the output log in xcode when my app displays a Save File pane.

The message is
StressIt[38940:6d83] [QL] Can't get plugin bundle info at XTUM/ -- file://localhost/Users/kalle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StressIt-exmfuiykgzqebkbxzzwzsuzawjyk/Build/Products/Debug/

I googled it and found out that it seems like a common error in OSX but can´t find any info about it relative to developing objective c. Does anyone have a clue what this is? Did I do something wrong? Can i fix it?

My stolen code for saving a file

```
// String to write
NSString * zStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[resultTextOutlet textStorage] string]];

// Get an URL
NSSavePanel * zSavePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
NSInteger zResult = [zSavePanel runModal];
if (zResult == NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton) {
    return;
}

// Store url where to save the file
NSURL *zUrl = [zSavePanel URL];

// Write file
BOOL zBoolResult = [zStr writeToURL:zUrl atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];

// Report write error
if (! zBoolResult) {
    NSAlert *writeError = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Error while writing file" defaultButton:@"OK" alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:@"Something went wrong whilw writing the file to disk."];
    [writeError beginSheetModalForWindow:appWindow modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a QuickLooks error generated from inside the NSSavePanel. I have the same issue, and there's no real way to make it go away; it seems like every single OSX-native file dialog spawns that message if there's a plugin on the end-user's system that's registered but can't be loaded. I *suspect* that in my case, going from Lion to Mountain Lion may have left an old QL PPC binary in the system. Since Apple no longer supports classic, the plugin can't be loaded. But that's conjecture. **What I know for certain** is: that's QuickLooks, not your program, and you can safely ignore it.